# vs code cant open directory on mounted folder "cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied"

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, mount

i am mounting my folder with

```
sshfs pc:/dir dir
```

this works fine. When I go to the mounted directory and I want to open vs code with this command

```
code .
```

I get this error:

```
cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

When I try to create a new file with nano test.txt and save it everything works fine and when I open vs code from my home directory and then open a folder and choose the mounted dir it works too. It does not work only when I want to open vs-code from command line.

Comment: it might be the implementation of `.` within sshfs. this might have to be a "I'll just live with that" problem.  can you try running `code <folder>` from the parent directory?

Comment: when I enter code mounted_dir/my_dir it works. Yes this seems to be the problem. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: when I go to my mounted dir and enter code my_dir it does not work

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio `code`](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has a built in [ssh extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) which will run all the commands/debug on the remote machine, much like the WSL, Github and Heroku plugins.

There is also an [sshfs plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kelvin.vscode-sshfs) although I've never used it

If you need to use sshfs the way that you are doing, then you will need to work through by trial and error the options from the [sshfs man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs)

I would suggest that you start with the ones to do with sync'ing caching and leave the "workaround" section till last